# How can I add a margin between a li and the border of a container div?

Tags: html, css

I have this `div` that contains an `h3` and a `ul` (the `li`s inside are inside custom svelte components):
[image: the rendered source code shown below]

```css
#projects {
  margin: 25px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  flex-direction: column;
  border: 2px solid #FF7F00;
  max-width: 50%;
}

li.projects {
  padding: 20px;
}

#projects-title {
  margin-top: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div id="projects">
  <h3 id="projects-title">Some of my projects!</h3>
  <ul>
    <Project name="RubyMod" href="https://github.com/theonlytails/rubymod">
      An free and open source mod for <a href="https://minecraft.net">Minecraft</a> 1.16, written in Kotlin using the <a href="https://github.com/MinecraftForge/MinecraftForge">Minecraft Forge    API</a>.
    </Project>
    <Project name="LootTables" href="https://github.com/theonlytails/loottables">
      A Kotlin DSL for creating loot tables in Minecraft mods (using Forge).
    </Project>
    <Project name="Cryptic Cosmos" href="https://github.com/Team-Cryptic-Cosmos/Cryptic-Cosmos">
      Minecraft mod for 1.16 that introduces exciting new dimensions, mobs, and blocks, made by the <a href="https://github.com/Team-Cryptic-Cosmos">Cryptic Cosmos Team</a>.
    </Project>
    <Project name="This website" href="https://github.com/theonlytails/theonlytails.com">
      <i>You are looking at it</i>. Built with <a href="https://svelte.dev">Svelte</a>, <a href="https://www.typescriptlang.org/">TypeScript</a>, and <a href="https://sass-lang.com/">Sass</a>.
    </Project>
  </ul>
</div>
```

how can I make it so the text in the `li`s is not touching the `div`'s border (like it the word "written")?

Comment: add padding to ul

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do this:

```css
#projects {
  margin: 25px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  flex-direction: column;
  border: 2px solid #FF7F00;
  max-width: 50%;
}

li.projects {
  padding: 20px;
}

#projects-title {
  margin-top: 20px;
}

#projects-list {
  padding: 10px
}
```

```html
<div id="projects">
  <h3 id="projects-title">Some of my projects!</h3>
  <ul id='projects-list'>
    <Project name="RubyMod" href="https://github.com/theonlytails/rubymod">
      An free and open source mod for <a href="https://minecraft.net">Minecraft</a> 1.16, written in Kotlin using the <a href="https://github.com/MinecraftForge/MinecraftForge">Minecraft Forge    API</a>.
    </Project>
    <Project name="LootTables" href="https://github.com/theonlytails/loottables">
      A Kotlin DSL for creating loot tables in Minecraft mods (using Forge).
    </Project>
    <Project name="Cryptic Cosmos" href="https://github.com/Team-Cryptic-Cosmos/Cryptic-Cosmos">
      Minecraft mod for 1.16 that introduces exciting new dimensions, mobs, and blocks, made by the <a href="https://github.com/Team-Cryptic-Cosmos">Cryptic Cosmos Team</a>.
    </Project>
    <Project name="This website" href="https://github.com/theonlytails/theonlytails.com">
      <i>You are looking at it</i>. Built with <a href="https://svelte.dev">Svelte</a>, <a href="https://www.typescriptlang.org/">TypeScript</a>, and <a href="https://sass-lang.com/">Sass</a>.
    </Project>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Just add `padding` to the `ul`!

> Note: I used `10px`, you can change this to your preference!

Answer (score 0):

You can add padding-right to the div:

```css
#projects {
  margin: 25px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  flex-direction: column;
  border: 2px solid #FF7F00;
  max-width: 50%;
  padding-right: 3%;
}

li.projects {
  padding: 20px;
}

#projects-title {
  margin-top: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div id="projects">
  <h3 id="projects-title">Some of my projects!</h3>
  <ul>
    <Project name="RubyMod" href="https://github.com/theonlytails/rubymod">
      An free and open source mod for <a href="https://minecraft.net">Minecraft</a> 1.16, written in Kotlin using the <a href="https://github.com/MinecraftForge/MinecraftForge">Minecraft Forge    API</a>.
    </Project>
    <Project name="LootTables" href="https://github.com/theonlytails/loottables">
      A Kotlin DSL for creating loot tables in Minecraft mods (using Forge).
    </Project>
    <Project name="Cryptic Cosmos" href="https://github.com/Team-Cryptic-Cosmos/Cryptic-Cosmos">
      Minecraft mod for 1.16 that introduces exciting new dimensions, mobs, and blocks, made by the <a href="https://github.com/Team-Cryptic-Cosmos">Cryptic Cosmos Team</a>.
    </Project>
    <Project name="This website" href="https://github.com/theonlytails/theonlytails.com">
      <i>You are looking at it</i>. Built with <a href="https://svelte.dev">Svelte</a>, <a href="https://www.typescriptlang.org/">TypeScript</a>, and <a href="https://sass-lang.com/">Sass</a>.
    </Project>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

How about adding padding to "projects"?
#projects {
margin: 25px;
display: flex;
align-items: center;
justify-content: center;
flex-direction: column;
border: 2px solid #FF7F00;
max-width: 50%;
padding-top: 50px;
padding-right: 50px;
padding-bottom: 50px;
padding-left: 50px;
}

Answer (score 0):

Run this:

HTML:

```css
#projects {
  margin: 25px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  flex-direction: column;
  border: 2px solid #ff7f00;
  max-width: 50%;
  }

ul {
  padding: 0 20px;
}

#projects-title {
  margin-top: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div id="projects">
  <h3 id="projects-title">Some of my projects!</h3>
  <ul>
    <Project name="RubyMod" href="https://github.com/theonlytails/rubymod">
      An free and open source mod for <a href="https://minecraft.net">Minecraft</a> 1.16, written in Kotlin using the <a href="https://github.com/MinecraftForge/MinecraftForge">Minecraft Forge API</a>.
    </Project>
    <Project name="LootTables" href="https://github.com/theonlytails/loottables">
      A Kotlin DSL for creating loot tables in Minecraft mods (using Forge).
    </Project>
    <Project name="Cryptic Cosmos" href="https://github.com/Team-Cryptic-Cosmos/Cryptic-Cosmos">
      Minecraft mod for 1.16 that introduces exciting new dimensions, mobs, and blocks, made by the <a href="https://github.com/Team-Cryptic-Cosmos">Cryptic Cosmos Team</a>.
    </Project>
    <Project name="This website" href="https://github.com/theonlytails/theonlytails.com">
      <i>You are looking at it</i>. Built with <a href="https://svelte.dev">Svelte</a>, <a href="https://www.typescriptlang.org/">TypeScript</a>, and <a href="https://sass-lang.com/">Sass</a>.
    </Project>
  </ul>
</div>
```

JavaScript:

```
import * as svelte from "https://cdn.skypack.dev/svelte@3.37.0";
```

The same can be found at https://codepen.io/babarkhan/pen/ExZMjKa.